Slurm remote task launch utility
We wish to know whether slurm uses "rsh/ssh" to launch remote tasks or it has it's own app/utility.
If it's the latter then what is it ( we use linux based platforms)?
For eg., scheduling engine LSF has a utility called "blaunch" for launching remote tasks. Is there a counterpart of blaunch for Slurm?
Else, we shall be left with no choice but to resort to rsh/ssh.
Problem is transitioning to rsh/ssh mayn't be always be smooth
in different slurm clusters.

Slurm offers the srun command to launch tasks. It can be used by the user to launch multiple processes, or to start an MPI program. It is also used behind the scenes a.o. by OpenMPI's mpirun to start MPI ranks on the nodes.

Thanks for your response. We do know a little about the srun utility. However, our use model employs launching remote procs from inside main task in primary node. Can srun be used as an alternate to rsh/ssh to launch remote tasks in any way?
